# how to do app for all devices using displaymetrics in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi am doing one app for all devices using display metrics.i tried using below code but in some devices like 1024/600,480/800 and density 160 its working perfect.but in some other devices like 320/480 density 160 text size is problem and app distrubing while displaying images.please any one having idea suggest me....

```
 register.class: 
  public class register extends Activity {
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
       float screenHeight,screenWidth,screendensity;
          float textsize1;

        @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
 screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
 screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
 screendensity = displaymetrics.densityDpi;
 Log.i("screenHeight",""+screenHeight);
 Log.i("screenWidth",""+screenWidth);
 Log.i("screendensity",""+screendensity);


 switch(displaymetrics.densityDpi){



 case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:

     //set text size
  textsize1=10;
     break;

 case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:

     //set text size
      textsize1=15;
     break;

 case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
       textsize1=8;
     //set text size
     break;
 }

    setContentView(R.layout.registerlh);


prntnm=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.parentedit);
    prntnm.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    InputFilter[] FilterArray1 = new InputFilter[1];
    FilterArray1[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(20);
    prntnm.setFilters(FilterArray1);


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parentedit1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)   prntnm.getLayoutParams();    
    parentedit1.height=(int)(50*(screenHeight/600));

    parentedit1.width= (int)(300*(screenWidth/1024));

    parentedit1.topMargin=(int)(330*(screenHeight/600));
    parentedit1.leftMargin=(int)(670*(screenWidth/1024));
 }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use dimensions don't hardcode values. for text use "sp" and images and others use "dp"

example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<dimen name="textsize">15sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

use dimen.xml files in each values folder(such as values,values-v11,values-v14) and provide appropriate size.

example to use those values:

```
textView.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
```

Comment: sory i didnt get u.i want to run app in 2.2 version onwards all above versions and all devices.

Comment: if that is the case, then create separate layout files (layout,layout-large,layout-xlarge,layout-small) also check this link http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html

Comment: thankyou.i completed whole app using displaymetrics.i strucked in text size.using display metrics any other solution is there to disply text in all sizes

Comment: the above one which i have mentioned is another solution to code different sizes for different views.

Comment: wats the problem actually in my code.i develop app in 1024/600 tablet.same app i run in  240/320 in this working well.but 320/480 in this device i am facing problem.

Comment: ur suggestion is good i agree with that.but whats the problem in my code.i want know the problem and i need to solve that one